# How to initialize view variables for a specific view configuration in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**If I have a method initializing specific variables to be accessed within a view like so:**

```
def define_personnel_attribs
    # Personnel editing variables include:
    # Array of all columns in Personnel model
    # Array of all columns to be displayed in table
    # Array of headers to be displayed in table

    @all_attribs = ["name",
    "role",
    "firstname",
    "middlename",
    "lastname",
    "address",
    "city", 
    "state", 
    "zip", 
    "homephone", 
    "cellphone", 
    "monthly_pay", 
    "years_worked",
    "current_assignment"]

    @table_attribs = ["name",
    "role"]

    @table_headers = ["Name",
    "Role"]
  end
```

**And I call it from another controller method like so:**

```
def admin_dashboard
    if render_personnel == true
         define_personnel_attribs()
    end
end
```

**Assuming a view called admin_dashboard.html.erb is to be rendered after the controller method is executed, and if render_personnel is FALSE, will the variables that are supposed to be initialized in define_personnel_attribs fail to be initialized and accessible by the admin_dashboard view?**

**Some background:**

My goal is to create a Dashboard view that only renders specific partials based on the type of user that logs in. For example, if the user is not allowed to view/edit Personnel via the Personnel partial (which contains a form for viewing/editing Personnel objects), then I don't want Personnel variables to be initialized.

If this is not the way to go about dynamically creating/rendering a dashboard for users please point me in the right direction. My background is primarily in desktop application development, with about 7 months experience in web dev (using C#, Javascript, CSS, etc.), and this is my first Rails application (teaching myself).

If more details are required please ask! I'm also on Freenode, in channel #RubyOnRails, under Arazon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninitialized instance variables return `nil`. If you'd like your view to tolerate that, do nil checks as needed.

> My goal is to create a Dashboard view that only renders specific partials based on the type of user that logs in.

This is just the kind of use case that partials are designed for. Best practice is to write small modularized partials that can be called as needed from multiple views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; does this mean I'm correct in assuming that if render_personnel is false, the instance variables won't be initialized?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Just do a: `if @all_attribs.blank?` or `@all_attribs.nil?` in your views to handle that case

Comment: Thank you very much! The way I have it set up, the partial that uses those variables is not even rendered unless the appropriate variables have been initialized but I'll add those checks just in case. Also, just wanted to verify that I'm approaching this Dashboard view the right way...I maintain something similar in C# at work but since beginning with Rails it's hard to find easy to understand examples for the things I want to do.